# Is it safe to manually delete old Docker images?

Tags: docker

I was start working on the Docker and I got some question regards on the docker images. Since each time when I create the new image and I will rmi the old images from the Docker, but looks like even after I run the commands `> docker rmi 'IMAGE ID'`, and when I cd into the `/var/lib/docker-registry/images` directory, it still shows lots of images there as below:

```
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   60 May 14 13:22 65de4a13fc7cf28b4376e65efa31c5c3805e18da4eb01ad0c8b8801f4a10bc16
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   60 May 14 13:23 4970b995ce6435831c0e700f7c3ce6363235fbd15333af2dfb60a133ee8e9226
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   60 May 18 11:24 edaa232fba2214030847b7f6f57b1c05cf92a7c607332495bfab21738ceb61e1
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   60 May 18 16:16 09dab15bb87d1273fce7d786b2443a1d68a6cdcd397443fed4b7ac1bac298d30
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   60 May 18 17:20 8a622b1faf8c1df7a1f97e8fa4b841803160a800d04f6af539044f6f22ae9a38
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   60 May 19 14:15 b823d1a073894fdb70f7a8846f4d14eb8a2f2842f047a3d8ad847343d576c2e2
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   60 May 20 09:38 7c3c8e970803c9487f1f8884eb17603efb442a31b6f2082f3b26592311264e92
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   60 May 20 12:31 9d36120c6870e16ff7917b05bbbb84061c70e3135e40b8a10d58b1d6f50b23a3
.....
```

But when I run docker images command it only show:

```
root# docker images
REPOSITORY TAG      IMAGE ID      CREATED        VIRTUAL SIZE
Images1    latest   f9a1d33ce592  14 hours ago   2.32 GB
Images2    latest   09dab15bb87d  9 days ago     877.2 MB
```

So here is my question: If something that I went wrong here since it won't delete the images folders under the `/var/lib/docker-registry/images` each time when I run `docker rmi`?

And if I can manually delete the images folders under `/var/lib/docker-registry/images`?

Some additional information:

I had found out under the `/var/lib/docker-registry/repositories/library/` directory, there include multiple images and most of them that I already used >docker rmi to deleted, but when I `cd` into one of the deleted image folder, it included multiple files as:

```
[/var/lib/docker-registry/repositories/library/deleted-images1]
root# ls -latr
total 20
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  159 May 27 17:39 taglatest_json
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   64 May 27 17:39 tag_latest
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  159 May 27 17:39 json
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root   75 May 27 17:39 .
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  304 May 27 17:39 _index_images
drwxr-xr-x. 14 root root 4096 May 28 10:15 ..
```

And in _index_images file which contain different ids as:

```
[{"id": "4970b995..."}, {"id": "65de4a13...."}, {"id": "f9a1d33...."}, {"id": "09dab15...."}]
```

So just wondering if this is caused the images folders didn't deleted from `/var/lib/docker-registry/images` directory when run `docker rmi`?

Is it safe for me to manually delete old images folders from both `/var/lib/docker-registry/images` and `/var/lib/docker-registry/repositories/library` folder?

Answer (score 3):

When you build an image, each line of the Dockerfile creates an intermediate image or *layer* that is not deleted until all other images built from that layer are also deleted.  You can see all of these intermediate image layers with `docker images -a`, and these should be the same as the contents of `/var/lib/docker-registry/images`.  (Either way, I would strongly advise against manually deleting entries from this directory.)

Comment: Thanks jwodder. and once I ran `docker images -a`. It only shows me four entries. but in `/var/lib/docker-registry/images` it had around 20 directories.

Comment: Here is what I run docker info it only show Images is 4.

root# docker info
Containers: 1
Images: 4

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the below command. It cleans most of the visible parts that my make your docker images list too bulky

```
docker images -a | grep '<none>'| awk '{print $3}' | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rmi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "clean containers ..."
docker ps --filter status=exited -aq | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rm -vf
echo "clean images ..."
docker images --quiet --filter=dangling=true | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker rmi -f
```